Why is a step/action in my workflow being skipped?
I'm using powerplatform-actions to set up deployment from my PowerPlatform / PowerApps non-prod to prod environment. I'm following this Microsoft tutorial guide.
I encountered this error like in this Github Issue.
> Solution Importing...
> Microsoft PowerPlatform CLI
> Version: 1.25.2+g1c4a1b8

> **Error: CanvasApp import: FAILURE: No file with that name found**
> **CanvasApp import: FAILURE: No file with that name found**

I followed the workaround mentioned in the GitHub issue, which is to force install Power Platform Tools as the first step of my job. But apparently, this step is skipped and my PAC version is not being updated (still 1.25.2+g1c4a1b8 instead of 1.31.6):
enter image description here
Here's my workflow:
name: release-solution-to-prod-with-inputs
# Reusable workflow
# convert solution to managed (using a build PowerPlatform environment for the conversion)
# upload the solution to the GitHub artifacts and deploy to the PROD environment
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs: 
      #Do Not change these values
      #Values are set by the caller
      #caller sample: release-action-call.ymnl
      solution_name:
        description: 'The solution name.'
        type: string
        default: deploymenttest       
      solution_shipping_folder:
        description: 'folder name for staging the exported solution *do not change*'        
        type: string
        default: out/ship/
      solution_outbound_folder:
        description: 'staging the unpacked solution folder before check-in *do not change*'
        type: string
        default: out/solutions/
      solution_source_folder: 
       description: 'folder name to be created and checked in *do not change*'
       type: string
       default: solutions/
      solution_release_folder:
       description: 'folder where the released binaries are going to be hosted *do not change*'
       type: string
       default: out/release
      BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_URL:
        description: 'Build environment url.'
        type: string
        required: true      
      PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT_URL: 
        description: 'Production environment url.'
        type: string
        required: true
      CLIENT_ID: 
        description: 'The client id'
        type: string
        required: true
      TENANT_ID: 
        description: 'The tenant id'
        type: string
        required: true
    secrets:
      envSecret:
        description: 'The secret value for authentication using SPN'
        required: true

jobs:
  convert-to-managed:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    # you can say runs-on: ubuntu-latest or windows-latest
    env:
      RUNNER_DEBUG: 1


    steps:    
    - name: Install Power Platform Tools
      uses: microsoft/powerplatform-actions/actions-install@v1
      with:
        pac-version-override: 1.31.6
  

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        lfs: true


    - name: Pack solution
      uses: microsoft/powerplatform-actions/pack-solution@v0
      with:
        solution-folder: ${{ inputs.solution_source_folder}}/${{ inputs.solution_name }}
        solution-file: ${{ inputs.solution_outbound_folder}}/${{ inputs.solution_name }}.zip
        solution-type: Unmanaged


    - name: Import solution as unmanaged to build env
      uses: microsoft/powerplatform-actions/import-solution@v0
      with:
        environment-url: ${{inputs.BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_URL}}
        app-id: ${{inputs.CLIENT_ID}}
        client-secret: ${{ secrets.envSecret }}
        tenant-id: ${{inputs.TENANT_ID}}
        solution-file: ${{ inputs.solution_outbound_folder}}/${{ inputs.solution_name }}.zip
        force-overwrite: true
        publish-changes: true


    - name: Export solution as managed
      uses: microsoft/powerplatform-actions/export-solution@v0
      with:
        environment-url: ${{inputs.BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_URL}}
        app-id: ${{inputs.CLIENT_ID}}
        client-secret: ${{ secrets.envSecret }} 
        tenant-id: ${{inputs.TENANT_ID}}
        solution-name: ${{ inputs.solution_name }}
        managed: true
        solution-output-file: ${{ inputs.solution_shipping_folder}}/${{ inputs.solution_name }}_managed.zip


    - name: Upload the ready to ship solution to GH artifact store
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: managedSolutions
        path: ${{ inputs.solution_shipping_folder}}/



  release-to-prod:
    needs: [ convert-to-managed ]
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      RUNNER_DEBUG: 1

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        lfs: true


    - name: Fetch the ready to ship solution from GH artifact store
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: managedSolutions
        path: ${{ inputs.solution_release_folder}}
    
    
    - name: Import solution to prod env
      uses: microsoft/powerplatform-actions/import-solution@v0
      with:
        environment-url: ${{inputs.PRODUCTION_ENVIRONMENT_URL}}
        app-id: ${{inputs.CLIENT_ID}}
        client-secret: ${{ secrets.envSecret }}
        tenant-id: ${{inputs.TENANT_ID}}
        solution-file: ${{ inputs.solution_release_folder}}/${{ inputs.solution_name }}_managed.zip
        force-overwrite: true
        publish-changes: true

I strongly prefer to set up the deployment with Github Actions, but if not, I'm ok with using Azure DevOps or PowerPlatform Pipelines.
I tried running on ubuntu-latest and using version 1.4.0 for all the powerplatform-actions but nothing worked.
I'm aware manually removing this node from the canvas apps metadata XML probably fixes it:
 <AdditionalUris>
  <AdditionalUri>solution_AdditionalUris0_identity.json</AdditionalUri>
</AdditionalUris>

But I'm looking for a workaround that does not involve doing anything manually.
